# Select Elements in a String Array

Tags: c#, linq

A have the string array and I need to select 9 elements starting from 20:

```
 string sel = data.Skip(19).Take(9).ToString();
```

Where is error?

**SOLUTION:**

```
string sel = String.Concat(data.Skip(19).Take(9).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Take(9)` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. When you call `ToString()` on it you just get the name of the type. You need to do this instead:

```
var selected = data.Skip(19).Take(9).ToArray();
```

`selected` is now of type `string[]` and should contain 9 elements (if `data` contains enough elements, that is).

Comment: why do you need `ToArray`? it will consume extra memory that might be not needed

Comment: Thanks, but I would not array.

Comment: @user348173 then what do you want? Can you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: string sel = String.Concat(data.Skip(19).Take(9).ToArray());

Comment: @Andrey, I just added `ToArray` because the OP was talking about arrays.